# How do I fix random <hr> / margins / paddings on wordpress page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I'm using elementor PRO to edit my wordpress website and I can seem to find a fix for these random lines / box overlay or whatever it is at the top or bottom of my page...

Here are some pictures that might help you understand the issue a bit better, thanks beforehand.

[Top of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I0YZ.png)
[Bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BocNG.png)

I tried to put on the css code the following code:

```
hr{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

And still had no success at all in solving this problem.

https://dev-fivemfuel.pantheonsite.io/elementor-223

Here is the site URL so you can review the problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the link to the website, that was super helpful! Unfortunately, I cannot tell you **why** the website behaves the way it does but I found a quick fix for the problem: The issue seems to be the header and you can remove the extra space including the lines by using this custom CSS:

```css
div#header, hr {
    display: none;
}
```

It's certainly not the cleanest way to fix this problem but it should solve your problem. :)